# Android Login/Sign Up Example

Tags: android, authentication, registration, autologin

I am trying to create an application which would require a Registration+Login system.

I want the Registration part to use the **user's photo**, their **email id** and their **full name** as inputs.

I have tried playing around with several existing examples over the internet such as :
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.html
however none seem to work in my favour. 
Based on my custom requirements for the Login+Registration page, could you please suggest some good tutorials/examples for me to look at?

Thank you,
Abhi

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: Kedamath, I looked at his tutorial to create a database using SQLite, but I did not pick much up from that.
I feel that using SQLite would be beneficial for me, for the most part.

Comment: Do you want to connect it to server database or local android database ??

Comment: Have you tried something ? We'll be able to help much better if you put up your code and tell us where you're stuck

Comment: yes, just provide the source code

Comment: Hey guys, I got really frustrated with building my own login system. So I decided to use the Facebook API starting today. 

Thank you all for your help.